# rails multiple models in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-models

Hi I have a model called `Event` and a form to create `events`. 
`Events` belong_to `Users` and should be created by them.

How is it possible to implement the `current_user.id` into a hidden field so that it will be saved in the `Event` table and belong to the `current_user`?

Thx.

At the moment it looks like this. But throws me the error:

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil,     use     object_id
```

My Form:

```
   <%= simple_form_for @event do |f| %>
     <% if @event.errors.any? %>
       <div class="error_messages">
         <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being   saved:</h2>
         <ul>
           <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
             <li><%= msg %></li>
           <% end %>
         </ul>
       </div>
     <% end %>

     <%= f.simple_fields_for :user do |id| %>
       <%= id.input :contact_name, :value=>current_user.id %>
     <%end%>
     <div class="field">
       <%= f.input :title, :input_html => { :class => "span10" }%>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an event that belong to the current logged in user, then probably you should do this way:

```
def create
  @event = current_user.events.new(params[:event])

  ## use your logic to save and redirect
end
```

I am assuming you have `has_many :events` in your User model.

Comment: thx. i worked it out in another way, see my own answer below. cheers

Comment: @user1884013 yes.. but in your answer you are mass-assigning the user_id but in general you should always use associations.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])
    @event.user_id = current_user.id
```

post this in the event controller. did it for me. current_user from devise method. 
Cheers